# How to get a list of C code functions ordered by length?

Tags: c, static-analysis

I'm analyzing a big chunk of C code and would like to split it into modules. Is there a way to automatically generate a list of C functions, starting with the ones that are the longest?

Comment: You could write a compiler. ;)

Comment: Re close vote: I'm not looking for a tool recommendation, but a solution to a specific problem.

Comment: Then please edit your question to highlight your "specific problem."

Comment: Decission was "to broad" or "serach for tool". Does it really matter which one?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we can assume that the line with a function declaration is not indented, ends with `{` and the function definition ends with a non-indented `}`, this Python snippet can help:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

started = None
started_line = None
for lineno, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    if line.startswith(' '):
        continue
    if line.strip().endswith('{'):
        started = lineno
        started_line = line.rstrip()
    if line.strip().endswith('}'):
        print("%s\t%s" % (lineno - started, started_line))
```

Comment: What if you have a ton of whitespace in your code? (e.g. empty lines) Will it accept that as "code" too?

Comment: @owacoder: It will, but you can easily modify it to count whitespace-only lines in a separate counter and remove it from `lineno - started`.

Comment: Another scenario: suppose all your functions have code on a single line. Now what? They'll all be classified as being one line.

Answer (score 1):

With the GNU userland (e.g. on Linux) you can use `nm -S --size-sort object.o` to get a list of symbols sorted by size from an object file. This should be approximately proportional to source code length.